# Issue While Installing Windows Phone 8.1 SDK

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Recently I have downloaded , Windows Phone 8.1 SDK , it was Amazing Emulators and it has More Features, but I can't install it. Follows is the error I have faced:

[image: Visual Studio Dialog]

Comment: Did you follow any of the links in the dialog? You'll need to edit your question to include more details of what you've investigated, relevant portions of the log, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but looks like you are trying to install the Update 2 RC without having the emulators installed. Note the "Update 2 RC does not apply" message.

Try to use [this link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394354) to install